# How to redirect and pass a strongly-typed viewmodel to another action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 controllers: `AliceController` and `BobController`. Each contains `Index` action method.
The viewmodel is simple as follows:

```
class Foo{[Required]public int data{get;set;}}
```

How to pass the strongly typed object from Alice to Bob?

```
class AlliceController: Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Index(Foo foo)
     {
         if(ModelState.IsValid)
         {
          // I want to pass foo to Bob's Index. How to do it?
           return RedirectToAction("Index","Bob");
          }
         else    return View();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In theory**, you can use the `RouteValueDictionary` parameter to `RedirectToAction`:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Bob", new { param = value });
```

**However**, you *cannot pass an object**via this type of redirection, only primitive types that can be tacked onto the GET url (int, string, etc).

Use **TempData** instead.

That being said, i have no idea what you are attempting to do.

Some concerns:

- Why not just pass the actual value, instead of the entire ViewModel?
- Why are you redirecting between controllers? (this can be done, just don't see the reason for it in your scenario).

Comment: In my scenario, I want to have a common `Confirmation` view. This `Confirmation` view is associated with `Confirmation` action method of `ConfirmationController`. `Confirmation` view accepts strongly typed model `IMyModel` to be displayed for confirmation. Other controllers are related to transaction of models implementing `IMyModel`. I want to use "Post-Redirect-Get" pattern, so redirect to Confirmation will be done for all transactions in my application.

Comment: @Stack Overflow - good to see your using PRG, and i understand your scenario now. I think your better of using TempData here.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just instantiate a BobController and return the result of the it's index method, passing in Foo?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you can pass a strongly typed object via Redirection.

You can instead pass just parameters

```
RedirectToAction( new RouteValueDictionary( 
     new{ 
          controller = "Blah", 
          action = "Blah", 
          foo = "Bar" 
     } 
));
```